# Как правильно: "Родина" или "родина"?

Tags: прописная-строчная, ономастика

И все-таки, как сейчас по правилам пишется слово "родина": с большой или с маленькой буквы? Понятно, что в случае "Россия - родина слонов" - буква будет строчная. А "родина" в значении "отечество" по-прежнему пишется с большой или сейчас существуют какие-то другие правила на этот счет?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Слово *родина* не является в полном смысле именем собственным и поэтому с прописной буквы пишется только в особом стилистическом употреблении, когда, например, высказыванию придается какой-то торжественный, патриотический смысл. У Розенталя подобные слова (Родина, Отчизна, Человек, Вера, Надежда, Любовь, Разум, Мудрость) подпадают под случай "Условные имена собственные". (см. Розенталь Д.Э. и др. СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ. М.: ЧеРо, 1999. Раздел III. Употребление прописных букв. §28. Условные имена собственные).